# Editing output of command as a new command

Tags: bash, zsh

I have a script that outputs a string that I would like to edit and then run as a command.

For example, I am using

```
cat ... | xsel -p
```

And then I want to edit the output of `xsel -op´ and run the edited string as a new command.

So I am trying:

```
cat ... | xsel -p
$(xsel -op) TAB
```

But this of course fails.

So how can I output the contents of `xsel -op` (in this case) to my command line, edit that new command, and then run the command?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [zshbuiltins](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=zshbuiltins):

> -z Push the arguments onto the editing buffer stack, separated by spaces.

To output content of xsel to your command line:

```
print -z $(xsel -op)
```

Comment: Ok, better than `print -s`, works on zsh

Answer (score 4):

You can get it added to history (at least in bash, I'm not sure on zsh) by doing the following

```
history -s $(xsel -op)
```

Then retrieve and edit it.

I've since found that

```
print -s $(xsel -op)
```

works equivalently under zsh

Comment: this looks like what I want, but doesnt work in `zsh`

Comment: I found you can do the same under zsh with *print -s $(xsel -op)*

Comment: you can even run `fc` immediately after `history -s $(xsel -op)` or `print -s $(xsel -op)` if you want to edit the command in $EDITOR (vi, nano, whatever).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than adding it to history manually, you can just press bash's `shell-expand-line` key (<kbd>M-C-e</kbd>):

```
   shell-expand-line (M-C-e)
          Expand the line as the shell does.  This performs alias and his‐
          tory expansion as well as all of the shell word expansions.  See
          HISTORY EXPANSION below for a description of history expansion.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do but something like this should work:

```
`xsel -op | sed 'do something'`
```

The backticks will cause BASH to execute, in this case, whatever is saved in X's primary selection buffer which you have just edited using sed. For example:

```
echo "find . -name foo" | xsel -p
`xsel -op | sed 's/foo/bar/`
```

The above commands will cause `find` to be run searching for files or folders named "bar".

Comment: Not really what I would like, I want to edit it in the terminal, not with `sed`